# Using $.get() to retrieve local HTML is not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have the following function which I use to render partial views in my app. Yet it is not filling the element I pass it with any content.

```
function RenderPartialView(view, contentcontainer, maskcontainer, params) {
     $.get(view, params, function (data) {
     $("#" + contentcontainer).html(data);
     $(maskcontainer).unmask();
    })       
}
```

I call this function from various methods with in my app and as of now have had no trouble with it. At the moment though, I'm prepending a div to the page  and then calling this function from a method like so in order to fill the div with the html data from RenderPartialView.

```
loadExpandedDashboard: function () {
    RenderPartialView('../Metrics/ExpandedDashboard', 'expanded-view', '#expanded-view');
}
```

everything works fine in all other browsers, in IE8 I do not get any console errors and when running basic error checking callbacks everything is clean. If I log the 'data' returned from the $.get() it shows the full length html that I am requesting from my own server. Because of this I'm completely lost on what could be the cause, Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Well may I made few suggestions... you should be passing the element to the function so you're second parameter should be passed as $('#expanded-view') rather then 'expanded-view' and then mapping it, that way classes could be passed. Same thing for maskcontainer.

Comment: Sorry the stuff part was accidentally left over from another test I was trying. It should say data, I made the edit.

Comment: Is it possible you have some malformed html in the partial view?

Comment: What happens if you replace your html() line with the following?

    document.getElementById(contentcontainer).innerHTML = data;

Comment: The app is built on the .net MVC framework so the html is formatted correctly but there are MVC related injections in the form of Razor code. That is not causing any issues else where in the app though.

Comment: @Peter strangely using the innerHTML method partially worked, it is bringing in getting the initial markup I wanted to display to show up. But a whole bunch of other areas are now broken across the app. I was under the impression innerHTML and the .html() accomplished the same goal, or at least were very similar...

Comment: @peter you ended up being right, there was an extra </div> in the mark up. Bah, so much time wasted. Thank you for the responses though guys!

Comment: @Stavros_S - glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that there is something in the returned HTML - missing or out of order tags, etc. - that IE is having trouble with. IE is known for being picky about the markup it accepts when in the html() method, whereas other browsers are more lenient.

Strangely, setting the innerHTML property directly sometimes works when jQuery's html() function does not.